# What does "Backpfeifengesicht" mean and is there a cognate in English?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I came across *Backpfeifengesicht* being used to describe someone running for office in the 2016 US election.

What is the meaning of or tranlation for *Backpfeifengesicht* in English?

Comment: The community here are not experts for finding English expressions. You should instead ask on ELU.SE (English Language & Usage), describing the meaning for their users.

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Backpfeifengesicht

Comment: @chirlu: how should people at ELU know what a "Backpfeifengesicht" is? Isn't this a question that need expertise in German rather than in English?

Comment: Maybe the question should be edited to "What does Backpfeifengesicht mean"?

Comment: Here is the possible reference to "backpfeifengesicht" in the US election http://www.rollingstone.com/politics/news/how-america-made-donald-trump-unstoppable-20160224

Comment: @Takkat: Because the OP would explain it to them, as I said above (“describing the meaning for their users”). It’s possible, as Iris suspects, that the OP actually wants to know what the word _means_; but as the question currently is, it clearly asks for a _translation_. And I, for one, don’t feel able to find an English equivalent that matches the tone.

Comment: I personally, can only guess what the german expression *might* probably mean, as I never heard it before.

Comment: @Iris Done, but with your link to Urban Dictionary it now looks like it could be closed here for General Reference reasons and could be asked at EL&U with the information found there. PS: „Slapface“ sounds like a gangster name from the 1920s.

Comment: Didn’t know that *Bockfotzngsicht* existed in standard German, too =D

Answer (score 3):

"Backpfeife" = "a slap"; 
"Gesicht" = "face"; so the literal translation would be "*Slapface*".

Meaning: somebody is so ugly that he should be slapped. But it has other meanings depending on the context and region.

Similar words:
Gesichtsgrätsche

Comment: In my understanding it is more that "someone is so annoying that you desperately want to slap him, everytime you see him (on TV)"